# Prevent Content Editor from automatically switching ribbons

Tags: content-editor, media-library, content-management, ribbon

On this one site, I frequently have to go in and deploy media items. In order not to publish things from other users that might not be ready, I publish the items individually.

One of the most annoying situations I keep running into is that media items automatically activate a contextual "Media" ribbon. I would prefer that the "Publish" ribbon remain active. As I try to quickly publish successive items, I often hit the "Deploy" button from the Media ribbon by mistake, since on this website it's perfectly aligned with the "Publish" button of the "Publish" ribbon.

The Media ribbon is useful, but I would rather it not to be auto-focused. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

The contextual ribbon is controlled by the `Ribbon` field on the template of the item you are on. So for images, it would be on either the `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Image` or `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/Image` (also could be on the `Jpeg` templates - depending on the type of image you uploaded). Those ribbon bars are defined in the core db.

[image: Image Contextual Ribbon]

If you don't need the menu options that are on that ribbon bar, setting the `Ribbon` field to `none` would stop it switching to the contextual ribbon when opening an image or jpeg item.

[image: After removing the contextual ribbon]

Although this will remove the contextual ribbon, it does involve changing a core Sitecore template, so the change may get reverted when upgrading. You also will lose the functionality that the contextual ribbon bar provided.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to avoid changing core Sitecore templates, you could consider another approach and adding a contextual right-click action to the item. That way it wouldn't matter what ribbon loaded because you would always have the right-click option available.

**Outlined here:** https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/08/20/simple-sitecore-tip-right-click-publish-item/

> In the core database copy:
>
> /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Publish/Publish
>   Item
>
> To here:
>
> /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default